# Como fazer uma filtragem de registros laravel

Tags: php, laravel, api

public function search1(Request $request)
    {

```
    $data = Cliente::where(
        'nome','LIKe', $request->nome . '%'
         'situacao',$request->situacao . '=')->get();

        return view('cliente.search',
        [
        'clientes'=>$data,
        'nome'=>$request->nome
        ]
    ); 

}
```

Comment: O que exatamente você quer fazer? eu percebi alguns erros no seu where mas pra poder te ajudar melhor preciso entender qual é a query final que você quer montar...

Comment: public function search1(Request $request)
    {
        
        $data = Cliente::where(
            'nome','LIKe', $request->nome . '%')->where(
             'situacao',$request->situacao . '=')->get();

            if(!isset($data['situacao'])){
                $data = Cliente::where('situacao',$request->situacao . '1'.'0')->get();
            }
        
            return view('cliente.search',
            [
            'clientes'=>$data,
            'nome'=>$request->nome,
            'situacao'=>$request->situacao
            ]
        ); 

    }

Comment: quero fazer uma pesquisa por nome e situação a situação retorna 0 e 1 só que quando deixo vazio o campo situação quero pesquisa o 0 e 1 como faço?

Comment: if(!isset($data['situacao'])){
                $data = Cliente::where('situacao',$request->situacao . '=')->get();
            }

Answer (score 0):

Você quer fazer um filtro por nome e ter a possibilidade de filtrar pela situação? é isso?

se for:

```
public function search1(Request $request) {
    $data = Cliente::where('nome','LIKE',$request->nome.'%');
    if(!empty($request->situacao)){
        $data->where('sutiacao',$request->situacao);
    }
    $data = $data->get();
    return view('cliente.search',
        [
            'clientes'=>$data,
            'nome'=>$request->nome
        ]
    ); 
}
```

Explicando:

Inicializamos o query builder com a condição que é obrigatória:

```
$data = Cliente::where('nome','LIKE',$request->nome.'%');
```

Note que antes de chamar o metodo `get()` a variável `$data` contém uma instancia do query builder, logo você pode adicionar filtros ou joins conforme precisar antes de chamar o `get()`.

Dito isso, vamos agora verificar a existencia do filtro por situação e se existir iremos adicionar o segundo filtro no query builder:

```
    //if(!empty($request->situacao)){ Editado, empty() considera 0 como vazio e 
    // não entra na condição
    if(!is_null($request->situacao)){
        $data->where('sutiacao',$request->situacao);
    }
```

Por ultimo, já tendo todos os filtros aplicados, chamamos o `get()` fora do if para garantir que a query sempre seja executada com situação ou não:

```
$data = $data->get();
```

Agora vamos retornar a view:

```
    return view('cliente.search',
        [
            'clientes'=>$data,
            'nome'=>$request->nome
        ]
    );
```

Sugiro a leitura da documentação do eloquen e do query builder do laravel:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent

https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries

Eles tem uma documentação bem detalhada e simples.

Comment: obrigado!! mais teve um pequeno erro porque quando seleciona inativo que retorna zero, busca no banco todos os registros, que no caso era só pra retornar só os inativos

Comment: @guilherme.ramos acontece que o empty considera 0 como vazio... neste caso troca o !empty por !is_null.

Comment: muito obrigado já tinha identificado esse erro !!

Comment: Que bom que funcionou! se minha resposta lhe ajudou, não esqueça de marcar como resposta aceita/resposta util...  :)